# How to determine default URL on .otherwise() without having resolve available

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set the .otherwise() using a rule function to determine the default URL.  I can't inject state or read the path since the application hasn't loaded yet, what I really need to be able to do is something similar to resolve within .otherwise() to check my UserService and ping the server for a session, since my UserService.isLoggedIn is undefined.  How do you handle having different default URLs where you really need something like resolve?

Comment: Can you please share sample code for the scenario to help understand the issue better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example in the official docs:  http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_otherwise

```
  // Example of using function rule as param
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
    return '/a/valid/url';
  });
```

You have `$injector` and `$location` so you can snag whatever you need.  You could even wrap it in an easy-to-read injectable function if you want:

```
function myOtherwiseFunction($state, UserService, Whatever) { 
  // check some $state stuff
  if ($state.current) { /* blah */ }
  // check some Whatever stuff
  if (Whatever.myFancyLogic()) { /* blah */ }

  if (UserService.isLoggedIn()) 
    return "/app";
  else 
    return "/login";
}

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
  return $injector.invoke(myOtherwiseFunction);
});
```

Comment: Lets say UserService needs to run a $http request first to assure that on route to .otherwise() a promise is successfully fulfilled, wouldn't this fall short in your example since it would be performed async, instead of using something similar to resolve() to guarantee the promise if fulfilled and successful before routing between dashboard or login.

Comment: Correct. .otherwise is synchronous.

Comment: I had no idea .otherwise was synchronous, so I can treat it like resolve and return a promise?  Thanks that's great to know.

Comment: No, it's synchronous, meaning the function's return result is used immediately after exiting the function.  It doesn't handle asynchronous promises.

Comment: Ah got it, sorry.  Would it be okay to create a route for handling otherwise?  For instance say .otherwise("/") and then have .state('default', { url: '/',..., resolve({ isAuth: ['$http', function( $http ) { ... return promise; }]);

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function isLogged in your otherwise function.

But... the thing is that you can't inject your service UserService in your config function (I suppose a bit) because it is not a constant neither a provider.

What you can do is calling you logging process in a constant that returns a promise like the resolve function:

```
.constant('login', function(){

  var access = function(UserService){
     return $q.when('start').then(function(){
       return UserService.initSession(); // I suppose you have a similar function
     })
  }

  access.$inject = ['UserService'];

  return access;
})
```

And in your config function:

```
.config([..., 'login',
...
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function() {
     login();
  ...
```